# Group by for multiple fields in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

In my project, I am storing user activities in a table *useractivitylog*. In one page I am displaying activities of logged in user's friends. I am using the following query for that.

```
$data['activityquery']=$this->db->query("
SELECT ua.*
     , rf.opid
     , aup.user_id
     , aup.first_name
     , aup.last_name
     , aup.profileimage 
  FROM useractivitylog ua 
  JOIN requestfriend rf 
    ON ua.userid IN(rf.userid,rf.friendid) 
  JOIN auth_user_profiles aup 
    ON aup.user_id = IF(rf.userid=$userid,rf.friendid,rf.userid) 
 WHERE $userid IN(rf.userid,rf.friendid) 
   AND rf.status = 2
   AND ua.userid != $userid 
 ORDER
    BY ua.date DESC;
");
```

This returns records as shown in below image.
[image]

I want to group the result on *activity_type* and *activity_id*. ie, as you can see, some records are repeating as the same activity is done in different times. I want to show only the latest record of the repeating entries.

I tried with

```
SELECT ua . * , rf.opid, aup.user_id, aup.first_name, aup.last_name, aup.profileimage
FROM useractivitylog AS ua
INNER JOIN requestfriend AS rf ON ( ua.userid = rf.userid
OR ua.userid = rf.friendid ) 
INNER JOIN auth_user_profiles AS aup ON aup.user_id = IF( rf.userid =  '1', rf.friendid, rf.userid ) 
WHERE (
rf.userid =1
OR rf.friendid =1
)
AND rf.status =  '2'
AND ua.userid !=1
GROUP BY ua.activity_type, ua.activity_id
```

This is giving me correct records.

[image]
But I also want it to be in descending order of *date* while grouping among the repeating records and also for the entire activities ie, the resultant records should also be in date order. Can anyone help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

DATABASE

```
CREATE TABLE `useractivitylog` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `activity_type` smallint(6) NOT NULL COMMENT '1-status 2-watch video 3-like 4-dislike 5-starring 6-upload 7-review',
  `activity_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=236 ;



INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(1, 1, 2, 2, 1399959912);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(2, 1, 4, 2, 1400062813);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(3, 1, 3, 2, 1400062815);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(4, 1, 4, 2, 1400062819);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(5, 1, 7, 3, 1400127388);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(6, 1, 7, 3, 1400127407);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(7, 1, 7, 3, 1400127667);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(8, 1, 7, 3, 1400127870);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(9, 1, 7, 3, 1400127933);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(10, 1, 7, 3, 1400127965);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(11, 1, 7, 3, 1400127978);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(12, 1, 7, 3, 1400128004);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(13, 1, 7, 3, 1400128022);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(14, 1, 2, 3, 1400138835);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(15, 1, 2, 3, 1400138923);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(16, 1, 2, 3, 1400139042);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(17, 1, 2, 3, 1400139044);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(18, 1, 4, 3, 1400139044);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(19, 1, 2, 3, 1400139046);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(20, 1, 2, 3, 1400139047);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(21, 1, 3, 3, 1400139049);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(22, 1, 2, 3, 1400139050);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(23, 1, 2, 3, 1400139052);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(24, 1, 2, 3, 1400139065);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(25, 1, 2, 3, 1400139169);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(26, 1, 5, 3, 1400147330);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(27, 2, 2, 2, 1400149323);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(28, 2, 2, 3, 1400149331);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(29, 2, 2, 3, 1400149357);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(30, 2, 2, 3, 1400149509);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(31, 1, 2, 1, 1400215110);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(32, 1, 2, 1, 1400215345);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(33, 1, 2, 2, 1400215350);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(34, 1, 2, 2, 1400215675);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(35, 1, 2, 2, 1400217939);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(36, 1, 2, 2, 1400218174);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(37, 1, 2, 2, 1400239850);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(38, 1, 2, 2, 1400240532);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(39, 1, 2, 2, 1400240562);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(40, 1, 2, 2, 1400240607);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(41, 1, 2, 1, 1400240610);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(42, 1, 2, 1, 1400240747);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(43, 1, 2, 1, 1400243642);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(44, 1, 2, 1, 1400303660);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(45, 1, 2, 1, 1400309276);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(46, 1, 2, 1, 1400309287);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(47, 1, 2, 1, 1400309851);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(48, 1, 2, 1, 1400309886);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(49, 1, 6, 8, 1400312651);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(50, 28, 2, 8, 1400556893);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(51, 1, 2, 2, 1400672617);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(52, 1, 2, 2, 1400672713);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(53, 1, 2, 2, 1400672739);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(54, 1, 2, 2, 1400672762);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(55, 1, 2, 2, 1400672875);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(56, 1, 2, 2, 1400672912);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(57, 1, 2, 2, 1400672929);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(58, 1, 2, 2, 1400672978);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(59, 1, 2, 2, 1400676486);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(60, 1, 2, 2, 1400676621);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(61, 1, 2, 2, 1400676644);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(62, 1, 2, 2, 1400676657);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(63, 1, 2, 2, 1400731951);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(64, 1, 2, 8, 1400734855);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(65, 1, 2, 8, 1400734885);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(66, 1, 2, 8, 1400734962);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(67, 1, 2, 8, 1400734980);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(68, 1, 2, 8, 1400734984);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(69, 1, 2, 8, 1400735391);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(70, 1, 2, 8, 1400737406);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(71, 1, 2, 8, 1400737448);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(72, 1, 2, 8, 1400737499);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(73, 1, 2, 8, 1400739069);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(74, 1, 2, 8, 1400739164);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(75, 1, 2, 8, 1400739298);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(76, 1, 5, 8, 1400739432);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(77, 1, 2, 8, 1400739435);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(78, 1, 2, 8, 1400739473);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(79, 1, 2, 8, 1400739511);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(80, 1, 2, 8, 1400740212);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(81, 1, 2, 8, 1400740373);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(82, 1, 5, 8, 1400740375);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(83, 1, 2, 8, 1400740378);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(84, 1, 2, 8, 1400740436);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(85, 1, 5, 8, 1400740438);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(86, 1, 5, 7, 1400740445);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(87, 1, 3, 7, 1400740493);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(88, 1, 2, 8, 1400740587);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(89, 1, 3, 8, 1400740589);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(90, 1, 2, 8, 1400740591);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(91, 1, 2, 8, 1400740594);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(92, 1, 2, 8, 1400740606);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(93, 1, 3, 8, 1400740607);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(94, 1, 2, 8, 1400740609);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(95, 1, 2, 2, 1400757648);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(96, 1, 2, 2, 1400817737);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(97, 1, 1, 22, 1400842234);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(98, 1, 2, 2, 1400903181);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(99, 1, 2, 2, 1400914246);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(100, 1, 2, 8, 1400914251);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(101, 1, 2, 2, 1400931063);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(102, 1, 2, 2, 1400931873);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(103, 1, 2, 8, 1400931898);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(104, 1, 2, 2, 1400931902);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(105, 1, 2, 4, 1401181831);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(106, 1, 2, 4, 1401181916);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(107, 1, 2, 4, 1401181943);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(108, 1, 2, 4, 1401182004);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(109, 1, 2, 4, 1401182060);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(110, 1, 2, 4, 1401182210);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(111, 1, 2, 4, 1401182379);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(112, 1, 2, 4, 1401182933);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(113, 1, 2, 4, 1401183001);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(114, 1, 2, 1, 1401183534);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(115, 10, 2, 2, 1401268400);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(116, 4, 1, 23, 1401268555);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(117, 4, 1, 24, 1401268696);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(118, 1, 2, 7, 1401347569);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(119, 1, 2, 8, 1401360692);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(120, 1, 2, 2, 1401421731);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(121, 1, 2, 2, 1401423782);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(122, 1, 2, 2, 1401423865);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(123, 1, 2, 2, 1401424526);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(124, 1, 2, 2, 1401424684);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(125, 1, 2, 2, 1401424751);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(126, 1, 2, 2, 1401424816);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(127, 1, 2, 2, 1401424823);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(128, 1, 2, 2, 1401424876);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(129, 1, 2, 2, 1401424879);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(130, 1, 2, 2, 1401424931);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(131, 1, 2, 2, 1401425095);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(132, 1, 2, 2, 1401425103);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(133, 1, 2, 2, 1401425114);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(134, 1, 2, 2, 1401425154);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(135, 1, 2, 2, 1401425157);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(136, 1, 2, 2, 1401425181);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(137, 1, 2, 2, 1401425192);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(138, 1, 2, 2, 1401425202);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(139, 1, 2, 2, 1401425213);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(140, 1, 2, 2, 1401425254);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(141, 1, 2, 2, 1401425323);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(142, 1, 2, 2, 1401425372);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(143, 1, 2, 2, 1401425384);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(144, 1, 2, 2, 1401425401);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(145, 1, 2, 2, 1401425440);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(146, 1, 2, 2, 1401425910);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(147, 1, 2, 2, 1401426717);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(148, 1, 2, 7, 1401430184);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(149, 1, 7, 7, 1401430211);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(150, 1, 2, 2, 1401432585);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(151, 1, 2, 2, 1401432653);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(152, 1, 2, 2, 1401454284);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(153, 1, 2, 2, 1401509582);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(154, 1, 2, 8, 1401519962);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(155, 1, 2, 2, 1401535507);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(156, 1, 2, 2, 1401535740);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(157, 1, 2, 8, 1401536035);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(158, 1, 2, 8, 1401536072);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(159, 1, 2, 8, 1401536086);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(160, 1, 2, 8, 1401536090);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(161, 1, 4, 8, 1401536091);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(162, 1, 2, 8, 1401536096);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(163, 1, 3, 8, 1401536099);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(164, 1, 2, 8, 1401536103);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(165, 1, 4, 8, 1401536108);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(166, 1, 2, 8, 1401536108);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(167, 1, 2, 8, 1401536116);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(168, 1, 2, 8, 1401536124);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(169, 1, 2, 8, 1401536130);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(170, 1, 2, 8, 1401536139);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(171, 1, 2, 8, 1401536145);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(172, 1, 2, 8, 1401541279);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(173, 1, 3, 3, 1401555253);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(174, 1, 4, 3, 1401555256);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(175, 1, 3, 3, 1401555257);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(176, 1, 2, 16, 1401771312);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(177, 31, 1, 25, 1401781021);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(178, 31, 6, 17, 1401781574);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(179, 31, 2, 16, 1401781752);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(180, 31, 3, 16, 1401781822);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(181, 31, 2, 16, 1401781827);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(182, 31, 2, 16, 1401781833);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(183, 31, 7, 16, 1401781882);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(184, 31, 2, 12, 1401781950);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(185, 31, 2, 16, 1401782018);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(186, 31, 2, 16, 1401782331);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(187, 31, 2, 12, 1401788551);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(188, 31, 2, 8, 1401788646);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(189, 31, 6, 18, 1401792941);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(190, 31, 2, 7, 1401793683);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(191, 31, 4, 1, 1401793773);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(192, 31, 2, 2, 1401793907);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(193, 31, 2, 2, 1401793982);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(194, 31, 2, 2, 1401794066);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(195, 31, 3, 2, 1401794092);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(196, 31, 2, 2, 1401794097);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(197, 31, 2, 2, 1401794472);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(198, 31, 2, 7, 1401794552);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(199, 31, 2, 8, 1401795205);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(200, 31, 7, 8, 1401795222);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(201, 31, 7, 8, 1401795226);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(202, 31, 2, 8, 1401795257);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(203, 28, 2, 8, 1401798261);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(204, 28, 3, 8, 1401798264);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(205, 28, 2, 8, 1401798269);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(206, 10, 2, 2, 1401872961);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(207, 10, 2, 2, 1401872973);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(208, 10, 2, 2, 1401872987);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(209, 10, 2, 2, 1401872999);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(210, 10, 2, 2, 1401873011);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(211, 10, 2, 2, 1401875866);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(212, 1, 6, 19, 1402056888);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(213, 1, 2, 1, 1402087162);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(214, 1, 2, 19, 1402088190);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(215, 1, 2, 14, 1402088315);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(216, 1, 2, 2, 1402091176);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(217, 1, 2, 18, 1402094939);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(218, 1, 2, 11, 1402094968);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(219, 1, 2, 14, 1402094974);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(220, 1, 2, 11, 1402094997);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(221, 1, 2, 18, 1402095000);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(222, 1, 2, 16, 1402095042);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(223, 31, 2, 19, 1402139568);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(224, 31, 2, 19, 1402139663);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(225, 31, 2, 18, 1402139696);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(226, 31, 2, 11, 1402139735);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(227, 31, 2, 11, 1402139762);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(228, 31, 7, 11, 1402139786);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(229, 31, 2, 11, 1402139834);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(230, 31, 2, 11, 1402139863);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(231, 31, 6, 20, 1402140324);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(232, 3, 1, 26, 1402330720);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(233, 3, 3, 4, 1402331176);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(234, 1, 2, 30, 1402342251);
INSERT INTO `useractivitylog` VALUES(235, 1, 2, 16, 1402393661);

CREATE TABLE `requestfriend` (
  `opid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `friendid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `requesttime` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `message` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `source` smallint(6) NOT NULL COMMENT '1- Gmail 2- FB',
  `requesttype` smallint(6) NOT NULL COMMENT '0 - Friend 1 - Invitation',
  `friendemail` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `status` smallint(6) NOT NULL COMMENT '1-send 2-accepted 3-rejected 4-unsubscribed',
  PRIMARY KEY (`opid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='Friend request/Invitations' AUTO_INCREMENT=26 ;



INSERT INTO `requestfriend` VALUES(15, 1, 0, 1394618441, '', 1, 1, 'alen.abram@neos.com', 1);
INSERT INTO `requestfriend` VALUES(16, 1, 0, 1394618441, '', 1, 1, 'jeena.mew@nesos.com', 1);
INSERT INTO `requestfriend` VALUES(17, 4, 1, 1395052826, 'Hi, add me as your friend', 0, 0, 'jeena.mathew@nteos.com', 2);
INSERT INTO `requestfriend` VALUES(18, 11, 1, 1395054447, 'Hi, add me as your friend', 0, 0, 'jeena.mathew@nteos.com', 2);
INSERT INTO `requestfriend` VALUES(19, 1, 10, 1395054521, 'Hi, add me as your friend', 0, 0, 'jeena.m@ntos.com', 2);
INSERT INTO `requestfriend` VALUES(20, 2, 1, 1400148560, 'Hi, add me as your friend', 0, 0, 'jea.mathew@neos.com', 2);
INSERT INTO `requestfriend` VALUES(21, 31, 28, 1401780582, 'Hi, add me as your friend', 0, 0, 'alen.abraham@nete.com', 2);
INSERT INTO `requestfriend` VALUES(22, 29, 1, 1402313081, 'Hi, add me as your friend', 0, 0, 'jeena.mathew@neos.com', 2);
INSERT INTO `requestfriend` VALUES(23, 29, 10, 1402313089, 'Hi, add me as your friend', 0, 0, 'jeena.mathew@jjj.com', 1);
INSERT INTO `requestfriend` VALUES(24, 29, 3, 1402313119, 'Hi, add me as your friend', 0, 0, 'nihal@gggg.in', 2);
INSERT INTO `requestfriend` VALUES(25, 29, 4, 1402313762, 'Hi, add me as your friend', 0, 0, 'nithal@nnn.in', 2);


CREATE TABLE `auth_user_profiles` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `birthdate` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `relationship` smallint(6) NOT NULL COMMENT '1-single 2-married 3-Engaged 4- Separated 5- Divorced 6-Other',
  `address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `zipcode` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `phone_no` char(12) NOT NULL,
  `country` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `work` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `registeredip` char(15) NOT NULL,
  `registerdate` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `profileimage` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'default',
  `gender` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `profession` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `aboutme` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `referral_balance` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `website` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `google_open_id` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `yahoo_open_id` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `facebook_id` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=29 ;



INSERT INTO `auth_user_profiles` VALUES(1, 1, 'Jeena', 'Mariam', 638649000, 1, 'fghfllgdfg', 'kochi', 9887888, '25896589518', 67, 'NNNooo', '127.0.0.1', 1393409056, 'cind.jpg', 1, '', 'sssssssppp', 2022.09, NULL, 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawlUhpWgJhYxjlgg8UjhsKR0u40IvYQrGZ0', 'https://me.yahoo.com/a/Yl_iKDxqkIJIvZ7y5KHTBdkNDw2L#79ed5', NULL);
INSERT INTO `auth_user_profiles` VALUES(2, 2, 'Kichu', 'K', 0, 0, '', '', 0, '8958698565', 20, '', '127.0.0.1', 1394014161, 'default', 0, '', '', 24.02, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO `auth_user_profiles` VALUES(3, 3, 'Nihal', 'Krishna', 0, 0, '', '', 0, '9878956895', 50, '', '127.0.0.1', 1394014661, 'default', 0, '', '', 0.00, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO `auth_user_profiles` VALUES(4, 4, 'Nithal', 'John', 0, 0, '', 'Kochi', 0, '8789565456', 15, '', '127.0.0.1', 1394083479, 'default', 0, '', '', 0.00, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO `auth_user_profiles` VALUES(5, 9, 'Krishna', 'K', 0, 0, '', 'Bangalore', 0, '98711111111', 26, '', '127.0.0.1', 1395051693, 'default', 0, '', '', 0.00, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO `auth_user_profiles` VALUES(6, 10, 'Jithin', 'Mathew', 0, 0, '', 'Bangalore', 0, '98711111111', 22, '', '127.0.0.1', 1395052731, 'default', 0, '', '', 0.00, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO `auth_user_profiles` VALUES(21, 25, 'sdfsd', 'rrrr', 0, 0, '', 'gfdg', 0, '98711111111', 62, '', '192.168.1.150', 1398412578, 'default', 0, '', '', 108.00, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO `auth_user_profiles` VALUES(23, 27, 'lol', 'lol', 0, 0, '', 'jdjdjd', 0, '8383838383', 19, '', '192.168.1.150', 1399607669, 'default', 0, '', '', 8.00, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO `auth_user_profiles` VALUES(24, 28, 'Milan', 'Milan', 0, 0, '', 'Kottayam', 0, '9656544664', 26, '', '192.168.1.151', 1400556770, 'default', 0, '', '', 30.00, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO `auth_user_profiles` VALUES(25, 29, 'praveen', 'pp', 0, 0, '', 'xzxxxxc', 0, '98711111111', 18, '', '192.168.1.150', 1400579597, 'default', 0, '', '', 8.00, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO `auth_user_profiles` VALUES(27, 31, 'Alen', 'Jose', 619426800, 1, 'goodwill,\nhardwork,\npraywell\n', 'Kottayam', 0, '9745460905', 67, 'no workk', '117.222.144.62', 1401780167, 'astra_logo_a.gif', 1, '', 'new to this site . seems to good in features.', 2722.01, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO `auth_user_profiles` VALUES(28, 32, 'Roshan', 'Rony', 0, 0, '', 'Delhi', 0, '98711111111', 26, '', '61.3.167.211', 1401954757, 'default', 0, '', '', 10.00, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: "But this is not returning the correct result" Can you show the result you get and the result you expected?

Comment: Any sample data set with desired result set ?

Comment: Without aggregate functions on the columns not in the GROUP BY the query will return an indeterminate result.

Comment: Are you after the row(s) with the earliest date for each (userid,activity_type,activitity_id)?

Comment: add order by date desc at the end of your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add another join that will be a self join to your `useractivitylog` table, this will join the row with maximum date per `activity_type,activity_id` group,see subquery with alias `ua_new`

```
SELECT 
  ua.*,
  rf.opid,
  aup.user_id,
  aup.first_name,
  aup.last_name,
  aup.profileimage 
FROM
  useractivitylog ua 
  JOIN requestfriend rf 
    ON ua.userid IN (rf.userid, rf.friendid) 
  JOIN auth_user_profiles aup 
    ON aup.user_id = IF( rf.userid =  '1', rf.friendid, rf.userid ) 
  JOIN 
    (SELECT 
      activity_type,
      activity_id,
      MAX(`date`) max_date 
    FROM
      useractivitylog WHERE  userid != 1 
    GROUP BY activity_type,
      activity_id) ua_new 
    ON (
      ua.activity_type = ua_new.activity_type 
      AND ua.activity_id = ua_new.activity_id 
      AND ua.date = ua_new.max_date
    ) 
WHERE (
rf.userid =1
OR rf.friendid =1
) 
  AND rf.status = 2 
  AND ua.userid != 1 
ORDER BY ua.date DESC ;
```

Comment: @khalid..I tried with this query. But the record corresponding to first_name Jithin is not coming.

Comment: @Jenz can i have a sample text data not image because i cannot create tables from image ,if possible please add sample data in text form then i can look into the problem

Comment: @khalid..As I was unable to create sqlfiddle, I have added the table data in my question. Please see my updated question.

Comment: @Jenz i have analyzed your jithin user corresponds to the `ua.userid with 1` so this clause `AND ua.userid !=1` is removing this user from record you can clearly see this output if you run my query without `AND ua.userid != $userid` it will give you better idea

Comment: I was excluding the member who is currently logged in (in this case with userid 1) from the query..

Comment: @Jenz see my update query i have test it with your provided result set hope it works fine for your production data